# spaCy's rule-based Matcher finds tokens longer than specified by the shape

Tags: nlp, spacy

I want to use the rule-based `Matcher` (spaCy version 2.0.12) to locate in text codes that consists of 4 letters followed by 4 digits (e.g. `CAPA1234`). I am trying to use a pattern with attribute `SHAPE`:

```
pattern = [{'SHAPE': 'XXXXdddd'}]
```

You can test it yourself with the [Rule-based Matcher Explorer](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=DOC123%20DOCC1234%20DOCCC12345%20DOCCCCCCC123456789&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22SHAPE%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22XXXXdddd%22%7D%5D%7D%5D).

It is finding the codes I am expecting but also longer ones like `CAPABCD1234` or `CAPA1234567`. `XXXX` seems to mean *4 capital letters or more* and the same goes for `dddd`.

Is there a setting to make the shape match the text exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I found a workaround that solves my problem, but doesn't really explain why spaCy behaves the way it does. I will leave the question open.</sup>

Use `SHAPE` and additionally specify `LENGTH` explicitly:

```
pattern = [{'LENGTH': 8, 'SHAPE': 'XXXXdddd'}]
```

Please note that the online Explorer seems to fails when `LENGTH` is used (no tokens are highlighted). It is working fine on my machine.